# The Partition table format in use on your disks normally requires you to create a separate partition for boot loader code- How to fix?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I am installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 10. I chose the Something else option and manually specified the root, swap and home partitions. Finally, when I click on Install now, I am getting the above-mentioned error(Requires Separate Boot Loader Code). How to Fix it? I am stuck here.

Comment: You should install Ubuntu in the same mode as Windows. Sounds like Windows is in UEFI mode on a gpt disk, and you are trying to install Ubuntu in legacy mode, which requires a separate 2M partition flagged bios-grub, which does not exist. Check your machine settings to select how the Ubuntu installer boots, it installs in the same mode.

Comment: Or are you using LVM & encryption?  If standard install, it should see the Windows ESP - efi system partition if booted in UEFI mode. Shows installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Also shows Windows 10 screens or similar to Windows 8
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi